# Which one makes more sense, writing models in django or creating a table then auto-generating the models?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm, software-design

We have designed our ER diagram for our database design but I don't know if it makes more sense to write models in Django from scratch or create tables in Postgres then use inspectdb. What are the disadvantages of the latter and which one is most commonly used in projects?

Comment: Django models are often "richer" in the sense that there is an `EmailField` and a `CharField`. Both will at the database, result in a `VARCHAR`, but the `EmailField` has validation (that the data is indeed an email address). You thus "lose" context when making the database models.

Comment: Incorrect, you can get the same validation via a check constraint in the database; so you do not 'lose' any content. Moreover it will be validated even when access is made outside of the Django model. That's one additional step to eliminating content loss. Basically it comes down to preference and how it's typically done in your organization.